# Faster way to iterate over rows

Tags: r

I'm trying to divide each row of a dataframe by a number stored in a second mapping dataframe.

```
for(g in rownames(data_table)){
print(g)
data_table[g,] <- data_table[g,]/mapping[g,2]
}
```

However, this is incredibly slow, each row takes almost 1-2 seconds to run. I know iteration is usually not the best way to do things in R, but I don't know how else to do it. Is there any way I can speed up the runtime?

Comment: first, get rid of the print. This makes it even slower

Comment: You can try `apply` or `lapply`. For your case, you might want to use `mapply` since you have multiple data frames

Comment: do they have equal number of rows? You can probably just divide the whole column at once, provided they are orderd correctly

Comment: Why is your `data_table` object not a matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
sweep(data_table, 1, mapping[[2]], "/")
```

In terms of speed here is a benchmark for the possibilities using `iris` dataset and including your version :

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
 A = {
     for(g in rownames(test)){
         # print(g)
           test[g,] <- test[g,]/test[g,2]
         }
   },
 B = sweep(test, 1, test[[2]], "/"),

 C = test / test[[2]],

 times = 100 
)

#Unit: microseconds
#expr       min        lq        mean    median         uq        max neval
#A 82374.693 83722.023 101688.1254 84582.052 147280.057 157507.892   100
#B   453.652   484.393    514.4094   513.850    539.480    623.688   100
#C   404.506   423.794    456.0063   446.101    470.675    729.205   100
```

Comment: The `iris` dataset is way too small for a meaningful performance benchmark

Answer (score 1):

you can vectorize this operation if the two variables have the same number of rows:

```
dt <- data.frame(a = rnorm(100), b = rnorm(100))
mapping <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))

dt / mapping[,2]
```